# Error converting data type nvarchar to datetime

Tags: sql-server-2005, datetime, type-conversion

I have the following procedure interface:

```
Create procedure [dbo].[InsertItemDetails]
    @TimeItemAdded datetime
```

When I call it this way:

```
EXEC [dbo].[InsertItemDetails]
     @TimeItemAdded = N'20/07/2012 00:00:00';
```

I get this error:

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5
>   Error converting data type nvarchar to datetime.

Comment: What value are you passing to the `@TimeItemAdded ` parameter in `InsertItemDetails`?

Comment: 20/07/2012 00:00:00  as  date and time

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41867371/error-converting-data-type-nvarchar-to-datetime-sql-server/68306836#68306836

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Depending on your regional settings, the parameter you are passing in for `@TimeItemAdded` might not be recognized.

You should pass the date in as:

```
20120720
```

Comment: This is not a safe format. `SET LANGUAGE FRENCH;
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, '2012-07-20 00:00:00');` yields `Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 2; 
La conversion d'un type de données varchar en type de données datetime a créé une valeur hors limites.` Safe formats for datetime are `YYYYMMDD` or `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.nnn` - that `T` is important.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - fascinating; removed the time for consistency

Comment: Still not language safe even without the time. The dashes are the problem. In French (and some other locales) this is interpreted as `YYYY-DD-MM`. Obviously there is no 20th month. `YYYYMMDD` is immune to this problem.

Comment: Interesting; we have some French sites, and I swear this has never come up, but I believe you.

Answer (score 3):

Use an unambiguous string literal for your date. In this case:

```
EXEC dbo.InsertItemDetails
    ...
    , @TimeItemAdded = '20120720';
```

Better yet, make sure to pass a strongly typed parameter where you know that the date is correct. Ideally, this should never be presented as a string in any format.

Regional formats like m/d/y are bad news, because you can't ensure that they will work given the user's session, dateformat, language settings, the regional settings on the machine, etc.

Answer (score 2):

SQL read your date as `7/20/2012` which is invalid, you may pass your date objects with safer format `yyyy-MM-dd` eg: `2012-07-20`

Answer (score 0):

This link has all the datetime formats, their conntries
http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx

You could pass it in as a varchar and explicitly convert it to a datetime using the proper date format code.  For example:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, '20/07/2012 00:00:00', 103)
```

103 is the datetime code you are looking for.

Comment: I don't agree that you should change the parameter to varchar. Fix the format (or use the right data type) as early as possible. If you change the parameter to varchar, people can pass in anything they want. `mm/dd/yyyy` will break, for example; `06/07/2012` will just store the wrong date silently, and `07/20/2012` will generate an exception.