# Error converting data type nvarchar to datetime SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I am facing a problem

> Error converting data type nvarchar to datetime

during inserting a date as a string literal in the format of `26/01/2017`. I am using this code in SQL Server during insert:

```
CONVERT(DATETIME, @PaymentDate, 104)
```

Comment: I think you should be using 103.  [MSDN Documentataion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx).

Comment: More reference here: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp

Comment: Can you share how you are declaring `@PaymentDate`?  This related question may help here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11651585/error-converting-data-type-nvarchar-to-datetime

Answer (score 3):

Try `CONVERT(DATETIME, @PaymentDate, 103)`

`104` is the German style which uses periods between the numerals, as opposed to slashes.  `103` is the British/French style.

See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Answer (score 3):

I've noticed your question is also tagged with [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23).
If you are passing the date from c# to sql server, 
Don't pass dates as strings. Pass them as DateTime.
The .Net [`DateTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx) [maps directly](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716729(v=vs.110).aspx) to SQL Server's [`DateTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx).
This way, you will not have to deal with the display format at all, since both c# and SQL Server does not store display format in `DateTime`.

If you really need to convert the string `'26/01/2017'` to date, you should use 103 for your style argument, as already suggested in other answer.

Answer (score 1):

This Example runs without any problem:

```
Declare  @PaymentDate  nvarchar(40)
set @PaymentDate = '26/01/2017'
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,@PaymentDate,104)
```

**Result:**

```
2017-01-26 00:00:00.000
```

Answer (score 0):

check the dateformat in sqlserver and then convert accordingly. code for dateformat
SET DATEFORMAT mdy

Answer (score 0):

Try these code, and make sure date value is not null and past 1970-1-1。

```
CONVERT(DATETIME,@PaymentDate,103)
```

Or

```
CONVERT(DATETIME,@PaymentDate,105)
```

Answer (score 0):

use SelectedDate incase you are saving your data and get that error
ie.
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("EndDate", EndDatep.DateInput.SelectedDate);

Answer (score 0):

The issue I faced was that the date was having the correct format but the time part was incorrect, the date was like

> 07/28/2021 00:00 PM

where 00 hours cannot be possible in PM, that is why DB was not accepting them while saving the date/time.
so I converted the date to

> 07/28/2021 00:00 AM

and it was saved. maybe helpful for anyone.